# Como manter banner de parcerias em site?

Tags: html

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde irei colocar banner de sites parceiros (toca de visitas) mas não sei como deve ser a inserção dos banners dos parceiros mas pensei em duas formas.

1. Inserir direto no `HTML` e manualmente definir o tamanho do banner (banner maiores para os parceiros que mais me gerarem trafego).
2. Salvar o HTML do banner (ex: `<a title="site" href="#" target="_blank"> 
   <img src="http://site/banners/50x50.png" alt="site" /></a>`) em banco de dados juntamente com o montante de visitas geradas por ele para que automaticamente o site acople o banner ao campo do site.

Qual das formas é mais usual? Existe outra forma mais adequada? abaixo um exemplo de banners de parceria retângulos/quadrados representam os banners sendo que os maiores são os banners dos maiores geradores de trafego.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu realmente acho que não existe padrão. *Mudando* de assunto, só para estudo, que tal dar uma lida neste link, é uma assunto relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14405396/1518921

Comment: Definir tamanho na mão vai ter dar um monte de problema de manutenção, é melhor usar um <li> e deixar o HTML definir o tamanho dos elementos automaticamente.

Comment: Respondi minha própria pergunta da forma mais simples que encontrei, se possuir uma solução mais arrojada que a minha ou algum questionamento / dica sobre minha arquitetura de solução, comente ou responda se sua solução for melhor a validarei sem dúvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manter os dados dos banners dos sites dos parceiros criei duas tabelas no banco uma pra manter o tipo do parceiro (acho opcional) e uma pra salvar os dados do banner:

```
INSERT INTO partner_type(valor, name) VALUES(1,'Big');
INSERT INTO partner_type(valor, name) VALUES(2,'Medium');

INSERT INTO partner_banner(partner_name, partner_url, partner_image, partner_type) 
VALUES('Site name','http://www.xxx.com.br/','http://localhost/xxx/images/temp/LinkExchangeBanners/70x70.jpg',1);
INSERT INTO partner_banner(partner_name, partner_url, partner_image, partner_type) 
VALUES('Site name 2','http://www.zzz.com.br/','http://localhost/zzz/images/temp/LinkExchangeBanners/70x70.jpg',1);
```

e criei estas funções para busca dos valores dos bancos:

```
    function selectBigPartner(){
        $this->selectBigPartnerCreateStmt();
        $result = $this->rowStmtExecute();
        return $result;
    }

        function selectBigPartnerCreateStmt(){
            $select = 'SELECT partner_name, partner_url, partner_image FROM partner_banner WHERE partner_type = 1';
            $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($select);
        }

        function rowStmtExecute(){
            $this->stmt->execute();
            $result = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($result)){
                return $result;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Esta solução funciona bem enquanto os banners são inseridos manualmente.

Comment: Respondi minha própria pergunta da forma mais simples que encontrei, se possuir uma solução mais arrojada que a minha ou algum questionamento / dica sobre minha arquitetura de solução, comente ou responda se sua solução for melhor a validarei sem dúvidas.